# .permission.has() discord.js v12 - Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined

Tags: node.js, permissions, discord, discord.js

I'm having trouble coding my bot for people who have `MANAGE_MESSAGES` to be able to say 'badword'. Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN

let set = new Set(['badword'])
bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) {
    return
  }
  let wordArray = msg.content.split(' ')
  if (!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
  for(var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    if(set.has(wordArray[i].toLowerCase())) {
      msg.delete()
      msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.username}, you said a bad word.`)
      break
    }
    console.log('message filtered')
  }   
}

})
bot.login(token)
```

The `.permissions.has()` is not working as according to this website https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#permissions-haspermission-s, it says that `.hasPermission()` / `.hasPermissions()` is now completely removed from v11 and added `permissions.has()`. Yes, my bot is upgraded to v12 so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use it is .hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')

```
if (!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
```

You're using the GuildMember class which uses the hasPermission() method. You were looking at the permission class.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember

Comment: I tried that but it said "Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined"

Comment: @LinkPigThrower I'm not sure if this is going to fix it but you do have "msg" in parentheses for bot.on and you don't really need them. I would take those out and then try again.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work as it still says "Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null".

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with the current code so I can have a better look?

Comment: From my understanding it’s msg.member that’s returning as null. I checked around and this seems to be an issue that can be resolved by updating npm packages

Comment: Sorry I got back to you so late but all my npm packages are up-to-date

Comment: @LinkPigThrower I tested it it now myself and it works fine for me so there is something definitely off somewhere on your end.

Comment: Does it happen right away or after a bit first?

Comment: I solved it, realizing that dming the bot makes the error happen. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm a new coder so I'm just learning new things.

Comment: No worries! I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I suggest having a bot testing server so you don't have to dm your bot.